# Delete all files from pendrive using C program

Tags: c, windows

I am searching for a solution to delete all files from my pendrive using a C program. I don't want the code to detect the pendrive as that's not a concern right now. I would appreciate any links that could help me out on this.

Note: I am working on Windows 7 64-bit and I want to delete the entire contents from my pendrive, which contains .exes and .dlls.

Thanks and Regards,
Radix

Comment: More details would be useful here. What operating system? What filesystem?

Comment: Deleting all files is not called formatting.

Comment: Removed DOS tag. Windows 7 is an NT variant; no DOS is ever entering the picture here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The non-hack *correct* way to do this, is via the [Virtual Disk Service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb986750%28v=VS.85%29.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

If you can't use something like `rm -rf F:\*` and you really do need to implement it yourself in C then I think I'd probably opt for a recursive solution based on [`FindFirstFile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364418%28VS.85%29.aspx) and [`FindNextFile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364428%28v=VS.85%29.aspx). These are the native Windows APIs for enumerating directories. Not remotely portable, but it doesn't seem that's a requirement.

Basically the idea is that you write a function, `EmptyDir()`, say, whose job it is to delete the contents of a directory. The function uses `FindFirstFile` and `FindNextFile` to walk the contents of the directory. When a file is encountered it is deleted. When a directory is encountered, `EmptyDir()` is called recursively. The last job of `EmptyDir()`, before it returns, is to delete the now empty directory.